Spring boot 3 trace Id tracking issue
I'm new to logging in spring. I read some articles about sleuth being replaced in spring boot 3 for tracking trace id aswell as span id. I have configured a logback-spring.xml as provided added the dependencies in pom but no luck so far. I have a custom enpoint defiend for throwing an exception and it doesnt include the trace id
this is the logback-spring.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [traceId=%X{traceId}] [spanId=%X{spanId}] [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
</configuration>

pom.xml
(ps. gelf is for later use)
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.siegmar</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>


I added the following dependencies:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:8.0'

And then I configured logback.  Note I use a JSON appender for my deployments and locally I use console appender.  I don't really need traceId and spanId locally.
<springProfile name="local">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="!local">
    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

I give credit to this article for some help: https://medium.com/@balloon.helps/spring-boot-3-logging-for-monitoring-1a42e157bcd9
